# node.js - setInterval & setTimeout incrementally repeating command

Tags: node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to help a friend setup a bot for `Picarto.tv`, we have the bot [LINK](https://github.com/Wolvan/PicartoChatBot) and there's no default `plugin` there for repeating messages, so I tried to make a very crude (seriously, it's terrible. I'm not a developer.) `plugin` for it, and I tried to use `SetInterval/SetTimeout`, and both times when I use them it will put the message in chat once, at the set interval, then it will wait, then after the interval it will say the message twice, then three times and so on.

It looks like this:

```
Time 1:  
Testing...  

Time 2:  
Testing...  
Testing...
```

And so on. Here's the code, as I said, it's terribly made, don't bash me too hard for it.

```
var api;
function handleChatMsg(data) {
    var recursive = function () {
        api.Messages.send("Testing Bot Repeat...");
        setTimeout(recursive,15000);
    }
    recursive();
}



module.exports = {
    meta_inf: {
        name: "Repeat Message",
        version: "1.0.0",
        description: "Repeats a message every 5 minutes. Message and interval can be changed.",
        author: "ZX6R"
    },
    load: function (_api) {
        api = _api;
    },
    start: function () {
        api.Events.on("userMsg", handleChatMsg);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me figure out why it's incrementally saying the message more times?

EDIT: Issue fixed, new code is

```
var api;
// Function to call for the repeating
function handleChatMsg() {
// This sets the interval of 5 minutes, and calls the variable. Edit the numbers after the comma to change the interval. You MUST put it into milliseconds.
setInterval(function(){xyz()}, 15000); 
// This sets the variable, edit the text in "api.Messages.send" to change what the bot repeats.
var xyz = function()
{
    api.Messages.send("Testing...")
}
}


// defines some information about the plugin, and sets up stuff we need.
module.exports = {
    meta_inf: {
        name: "Repeat Message",
        version: "1.1.1",
        description: "Repeats a message every 5 minutes. Message and interval can be changed.",
        author: "ZX6R"
    },
load: function (_api) {
      api = _api;
  },
    start: function () {
        handleChatMsg();
    }
}

// The MIT License (MIT)

// Copyright (c) 2016 RedFalconv2 - ZX6R - WalnutGaming

//Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's not complicate things and make it simpler.

```
setInterval(function(){xyz()}, 300000); 

var xyz = function()
{
    //Do what you want your function to do.
}
```

Here function xyz will be called every 300,000 milliseconds which means 5 minutes.

Take a look at [Node Cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) btw if you are going to use it regularly for an application.

Comment: While that is a little cleaner than my earlier thing, it still keeps adding more Testing...'s after the first time. I think its related to                      'start: function () {
        api.Events.on("userMsg", handleChatMsg);
    }
}'

Comment: It seems like it could be detecting the message it sends, then running the setinterval AGAIN. But, the plugin wont load without this api.Events.on or the function before everything.

Comment: I was right, I changed it to just call the "handleChatMsg" function in the beginning, and now it works properly! By the way, do you think Node Cron would be better, or this method? I want to just leave the bot on its own running, and just leave it on between streams, because a lot of the time I miss the streams my friend does.

Comment: If you are using it for an application then obviously I think node-cron will be a better option. Generally professionals would suggest you to use that but in the end take decision based upon your analysis. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
// define and export module
var plugin = {};
module.exports = plugin;

// plugin metadata
plugin.meta_inf = {
        name: "Repeat Message",
        version: "1.0.0",
        description: "Repeats a message every 5 minutes. Message and interval can be changed.",
        author: "ZX6R"
    };

/**
 * To be called on plugin load.
 * @param {Object} api - api instance.
 */
plugin.load = function(api){
   plugin._api = api;
};

/**
 * Called on plugin start.
 */
plugin.start = function(){

   if(!plugin._api){
      // api instance should have been available
      throw new Error("api not defined, is plugin load()'ed ?");
   }

   // each user message event (re)configures the repeating timer
   plugin._api.Events.on("userMsg",function(){
      plugin._configure(true, "Testing echo bot...",15000);
   });
};

/**
 * Configure the repeating timer
 * @param {Boolean} enabled - true to enable timer, false to disable
 * @param {String} message - message to repeat, required if enabled
 * @param {Number} interval - milliseconds between repeats, required if enabled
 */
plugin._configure = function(enabled, message, interval){

   if(plugin._timer){
      // always clear any old timer
      clearInterval(plugin._timer);
   }

   if(enabled){
      if(!message || !interval){
        // message and interval are required
        throw new Error("message and interval are required.");
      }

      // set a repeating timer
      plugin._timer = setInterval(function(){
         plugin._api.Messages.send(message);
      },interval);
   }

};
```

Notes:

1. user message events apply a new setting on timer. You can have the bot repeat user message, or something custom.
2. Or, you can only configure the timer once.

Comment: Thanks, but I have solved the issue, I had the start plugin variable set to call the "setinterval" on a user message, no clue why I had it that way. I set it to call the setinterval once, and now its working!